# TicTok Shop API to get direct messages

Tags: tiktok

I have seen the gorgias.com web site have the ability to pull in messages from a sellers TicTok Shop. However I can not find the API documentation on where/how I could pull in and be able to respond to TicTok shop messages.

Has anyone seen or have a link they know of ?